# QuickBooks 2008 template formatting

Tags: formatting, templates, quickbooks

I am trying to create an invoice template, and need to display the first line of the description in bold, with the rest of the description *UNDER* it, and NOT bold. Is there any way to do this, or do I need to look for a third party solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done.  There are third party solutions, but since al our relevant data is also stored in a SQL server, I ended up using reporting services